# I want an input to break if a "q" is entered but Spyder is giving me indentation errors

Tags: python, loops, break

As the title states, I just want to end the program if the user enters the letter "q" upon prompt:

```
in_str = input("Enter the purchase price (xx.xx) or 'q' to quit: ")
in_str=float(in_str)
if in_str == "q":
    break
```

However, Spyder is says that the break is outside of the loop, yet if I backspace it, it says it needs an indent. How is this resolved?

Comment: You haven't shown any loop. Is the whole thing you've shown indented under a `for` or `while`?

Comment: Check that the indentation is consistent in the whole file. You can use spaces or tabs but not mixed.

Comment: BTW, your `float(in_str)` call will throw an exception if `in_str == "q"`, so you'll never reach the `if`. If you want `in_tr == "q":` to be reached, you need to put it **before** the `float()` conversion. (And ideally, you should be storing the float to a different variable name than the original string -- otherwise, you have a float in a variable whose name explicitly says it's a string!)

Comment: As for the code you gave here, it doesn't actually *have* any indentation error. Your original code may have had such an error, but what you posted here doesn't. Always test that what you're posting actually produces the problem you're asking about on its own (without the larger context from which it's taken) -- this is part of the "verifiable" element of building a [mcve].

Comment: I realized that as well, that the float needed to be defined after the break. I'll be working on clarification as time goes on... so new to this I don't even know how to ask questions properly... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
in_str = input("Enter the purchase price (xx.xx) or 'q' to quit: ")
if in_str == "q":
    print("End...")
else:
    in_str=float(in_str)
    # more stuffs
```

First, you must verify your string, to check if `q` was typed by user.
An then, if not, do your logic with properly `float` conversion.

Comment: It's *legal*, but why are you varying the indention between the `if` clause and the `else` clause?

Comment: You also aren't actually answering the question (which can't be answered as stated), but just copying Charles Duffy's comment as an answer.

Comment: but, i didnt mean it, to copy the answer given. I just make my own version of answer and post it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the input from you, as well as another realization, I got it figured out;

The entire thing was put under a "while" loop, which I needed to do anyway. That, plus tweaking the indentation of the "else" fixed my problems.